# Xcode debugger shows variable name rather than value

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I've only started seeing this lately, I'm now running Version 8.2.1. When I hover over a variable name while in break mode, the variable often does not display its value, but its name. The same is true in the variables pane at the bottom of the screen. Using p or po returns an error. Here is an example of the code:

```
    let h = Double(Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date))
    let m = Double(Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date))
    let f: Double
    if h == 0 && m == 0 {
```

If i break on the first line and then continue one line, when I hover over h it says 5. If I then hit F6 two more times, hovering over h now displays "h". The pane at the bottom says "h (Double)" with no value, and using p returns:

```
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'h'
h
```

My code is pure Swift3, not a single line of OC anywhere. I assume the behaviour is because of the error, but why the error?

Comment: It works fine here when adding `let date = Date()`. Try if the issue persists in a new virgin project, to isolate the root of the issue.